# html5 canvas element disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, canvas

I have a `<canvas>` element that I put in a div using jQuery.  The lines I draw on that canvas appear and then disappear very quickly.

When I put text inside the `$('#solutionDiv')` div, it appears when the page loads, and then gets covered (briefly) by my canvas, and then reappears when the canvas vanishes.  This happens in FireFox and Chrome.  I am using a library for sliders called `tigra_slider_control`.  I don't think that's the issue, but it might be.

```
var solnCanvas=document.createElement('canvas'); // should be accessible through $('#solutionDiv > canvas')
solnCanvas.width = 480;
solnCanvas.height = 480;
var solnContext=solnCanvas.getContext('2d');
solnContext.strokeStyle = '#00f'; // blue lines
solnContext.lineWidth = 4;
solnContext.moveTo(50,16);
solnContext.lineTo(50,5);
solnContext.lineTo(5,5);
solnContext.stroke();
$('#solutionDiv').append(solnCanvas);
```

The corresponding div is:

```
    <div id="solutionDiv" style="width:580px;height:500px;" class="boxy">            
        Now you see it ... <br />
        Now you don't
    </div>
```

I don't need (or want) text in this div.  This is just for experimenting ...  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can u share jsfiddle for the problem

Comment: [what did you expect to happen?](http://jsfiddle.net/DSH9q/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is my long-awaited answer to my own question.  It seems to have had something to do with the fact that I was dynamically adding the div and the canvas.  When I added the div and the canvas in the html at the very outset, the canvas stayed put.  This is not exactly a solution -- more of a workaround.  Rather than adding the canvas later on, I just made it visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need (or want) the text in the `div`, [take the text out of the `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/DSH9q/1/).

Comment: Thanks for this tip.  My issue is that the `canvas` element disappears with or without the text in that div.  I have just forked the JSFiddle you created.  I'll incrementally add the rest of my code and see where it's breaking ....